# The number of local extreme points

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $n$ local extreme points, where $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that $f\circ f$ has at most $n^2+2n$ local extreme points.

Honestly, I don't know how I should start this, even for small $n$-s. This seems to look like a derivability problem, but we know that continuity doesn't imply derivability, so I'm not sure if we can use theorems such as Fermat's Theorem. Can you help me on this one?

Comment: What is the expression for the first derivative of $ \ f( \ f(x) \ ) \ $ ?  Your concern is legitimate, but we only will need the first derivative of $ \ f(x) \ $ to exist.  We have been told that it does because the presence of extrema is mentioned.

Comment: Yes, you are right! We only need the first derivative to exist for the derivative of $f\circ f$, but I didn't know that the local extreme points imply the derivability of the function. Can you give me a short explanation for it?

Comment: What is the derivative of $ \ f(x) \ $ at one of its maxima or minima?  Yes, the function _could_ have "kinks", but keep in mind that you are asked to find the _greatest possible_ number of extrema for $ \ f ( \ f(x) \ ) \ . $ For certain functions, the number _could_ be zero; what needs to be true to have $ \ n^2 \ + \ 2n \ $ extrema?

Comment: From Fermat's Theorem, in the extreme points we have $f'(x) = 0$. In order to have $n^2+2n$ points of extreme, we need to have $(f(f(x)))' = f'(f(x))*f'(x) = 0$ for $n^2+2n$ values of x. We already have $n$ of them, since $f'(x) = 0$ for $n$ values of x, but how can we find the rest of them? Can you expand a bit more?

Comment: (Sorry for the delay, but it was very-late-night where I am.) To get as many extrema as possible, we want some decently-behaved continuous function like a polynomial. Choosing a degree-$(n+1) \ $  polynomial will give us up to $ \ n \ $  local extrema. If we compose this on itself, we will have a degree-$(n+1)^2 \ $  polynomial.  Root-multiplicities or functions with non-differentiable local extrema will have fewer extrema in their composition functions.

Comment: When I tried this out experimentally, $ \ f( \ f(x) \ ) \ $ for a suitable polynomial has $ \ n \ $ local extrema in the neighborhood of each of its $ \ (n+1) \ $ zeroes, plus $ \ n \ $ extrema still at the values of $ \ x \ $ where $ \ f(x) \ $ has its extrema.  So that suggests how the proof should be made.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! They were very helpful!